How can I round up numbers in increments of 0.5?
In Google Sheets I'm trying to calculate variable shipping costs.
Shipping cost is calculated by adding a fixed base price to the product of the item's weight in kg and the rate per kg:
cost = base + (weight * rate)

For example:
base=$17.49  weight=2.5 kg
rate=$5.45/kg
––––––––––––––––––––––––––
= base + (weight * rate)
= $17.49 + (2.5 * $5.45)
= $31.12

The problem I'm having is that the weights must be entered in increments of 0.5 kg (500 g) and I can't figure out how to round up to 0.5.
For example, a weight of 2.1 kg should be rounded up to 2.5 , 2.51 to 3 , etc.

CEILING
Sheets native function to do exactly what you want.
=CEILING(A1,0.5)

# Array version
=INDEX(IF(A1:A, CEILING(A1:A,0.5),))
ROUNDUP
This function can be adapted to behave like CEILING.
=ROUNDUP(A1/0.5)*0.5

# Array version
=INDEX(IF(A1:A, ROUNDUP(A1:A/0.5)*0.5,))

Thank you so much, this was perfect!
